# What does "Supported ISO: no" mean in Fedora installer?

Tags: fedora, iso, installer-anaconda

I just installed Fedora Workstation 30. On boot, I selected "Test this media & start Fedora-Workstation-Live". The screen shows:

```
/dev/disk/by-label/Fedora-WS-Live-30-1-2:   b340a38cf5c1f09fdd769e259e449119
Fragment sums: 6dc04c22c2275... (a bit long to type)
Fragment count: 20
Supported ISO: no
Press [Esc] to abort check.
Checking: 025.5%
```

And completes the check successfully. I created the USB media from Etcher (IIRC) on Windows 10.

The installation is alright, but I'm a bit puzzled by the "Supported ISO: no" line, even though this ISO comes straight from the getfedora.org website.

**What on earth does "Supported ISO: no" mean?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The option "Test this media" actually sets the `rd.live.check` dracut command line option, which in turn triggers [Anaconda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaconda_(installer)), the installer, to test the installation media, by running the systemd `checkisomd5` one-shot service. The definition for this service is:

```
[Unit]
Description=Media check on %f
DefaultDependencies=no
Before=shutdown.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=no
ExecStart=/bin/checkisomd5 --verbose %f
StandardInput=tty-force
StandardOutput=inherit
StandardError=inherit
TimeoutSec=0
```

The `checkisomd5` command (see [here](https://linux.die.net/man/1/checkisomd5)) is provided by the `isomd5sum` package in Fedora:

```bsh
[root@fedora30 /]# dnf provides checkisomd5
Last metadata expiration check: 0:02:27 ago on Tue 03 Sep 2019 09:31:46 AM CEST.
isomd5sum-1:1.2.3-5.fc30.x86_64 : Utilities for working with md5sum implanted in ISO images
Repo        : fedora
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/bin/checkisomd5
```

So let's check the source:

```bsh
rpm -ivh https://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/releases/30/Everything/source/tree/Packages/i/isomd5sum-1.2.3-5.fc30.src.rpm
cd /root/rpmbuild/SOURCES/
tar -xvf 1.2.3.tar.gz
cd isomd5sum-1.2.3
```

Going through the source, you'll find a few references to the `supported` flag, which apparently means:

```
Indicate that the image will be written to a "supported" media, such as pressed CD.  On Red Hat-based Anaconda installers, this bypasses the prompt to check the CD.
```

which agrees with the man page at https://linux.die.net/man/1/implantisomd5.

So, "Supported ISO: no" means that this image wasn't flagged with the "supported" flag at creation time. This will make Anaconda show the prompt to check the CD.

Comment: You should probably add a conclusion. "Seeing `Supported ISO: no` therefore means...".

Comment: Perfect explanation. Thank you!